# Finding the inflection point(s) of a function

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$$

Sketch the graph of $f(x)$ 
and label all the critical points $C(x, y)$ and inflection
points $I(x, y)$ on the graph.

So I've got the critical points at $$C(0,0), C(1/2,1/16), C(1,0)$$

And then I've calculated the second derivate of $f(x)$
Which is $$f''(x) = 1/2 ± (√5/3)/2$$
$$= -0.1455$$ and $$1.1455$$
Then inserting this in $f(x)$
$$f(-0.1455) = -0.01545$$
$$f(1.1455)  = 0.2716$$

But looking at the graph it doesn't look like inflection points, so is it wrong or can any body help me?

Comment: What are your formulas for f' and f''? Since f is a quartic, f' and f'' would be cubic and quadratic, respectively.

Comment: $$f'(x) = 4x^3 - 6x^2 -2x $$ and $$f''(x) = 12x^2-12x-2$$

Comment: @Vicccc You've got the wrong sign for one of your terms in $f'(x)$.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just differentiate $x^2(x-1)^2$ with the product rule, as $(x^2)'(x-1)^2+x^2((x-1)^2)'$ and then use the chain rule. It's easy to lose minus signs when you expand everything.

Comment: @Jam It was a typo, $$f'(x)= 4x^3-6x^2 +2x $$ That's what I've written down

Comment: Is the sign in $f''(x)$ a typo too?

Comment: @Vicccc I don't quite see what you've done in your line $f''(x)=1/2+\ldots$. Are you finding the roots of $f''(x)$ here? Because if so, your notation should be something like $f''(x)=0\Rightarrow x=\ldots$ but also, you should get the $x$ in Gimusi's answer.

Comment: @Jam I see what i did wrong now.. Got it right now I think, Inflection points at$$I(0.211,0.027) $$ and $$I(0.211, 0.788) $$. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Vicccc Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$f'(x) = 4x^3 - 6x^2 +2x\implies x=0,\, x=\frac12,\,x=1$$

$$f''(x) = 12x^2-12x+2=0 \implies x=\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}$$

thus there are two inflection points.

Comment: Are you sure that $f'(x)$ is correct?

Comment: @Jam Ops...typo fixed! Thanks

Comment: Typo on $f''(x)$ too :)

Comment: @Jam Yes, it was a consistent typo! :)

Comment: @Jam Yeah it was tho :)